# Regex for MongoDB query

Tags: regex, mongodb

I need to find all data matching with string who looking like this :

```
16041917
16041917-A
16041917-Z
```

So as you can see sometimes I can get `-X` suffix or sometimes no.

In my code I have the value of the number but I don't know if there is a suffix or not. So I try to make a regex to find if the number exist in my database.

```
{number : {$regex: "^16041917|^-[A-Z]$"}}
```

It works but I don't know if my regex will work for everything. Can you tell me if you have better ?

Comment: Try `"^[0-9]{8}(?:-[A-Z])?$"`

Comment: I don't want to get all number matching with this patern. I want specific number that is why I put the number inside my regex. This will be used like a variable in my code. I think my example is confusing I'll edit

Comment: try this  `16041917(-[A-Z])?$`

Comment: It works yes but I think I need to append ^ at the beginning because it will match if I type `41917(-[A-Z])?$` and I want the exactly number

Comment: I suggested `[0-9]` because in your [initial question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/52147658/1) you said you wanted to match `18689784` and `18689784-G`. To only match specific number, just use it instead of `[0-9]{8}`. `"^16041917(?:-[A-Z])?$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match any string starting with `16041917` and then having an optional sequence of `-` followed with a single uppercase ASCII letter use

```
"^16041917(?:-[A-Z])?$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Sa8xf/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `16041917` - a literal substring
- `(?:-[A-Z])?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter
- `$` - end of string.